# Convergent $\{a_n\}$ $\nRightarrow$ convergent $\{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ converges and $\forall n \; a_n \neq 0$. Then $\{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\}$ converges.

How to disprove this?

Comment: By giving a counterexample. What would $a_n$ need to converge to for the limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ not to exist?

Comment: Try $a_n = 1/n$

Comment: You mean, zero?

Comment: @TomCollinge $\lim \frac{n}{n+1} = 1$

Comment: Yes, my mistake: I was thinking of summing $a_n / a_{a+1}$ (but not $a_n)$

Comment: Right, you need $a_n \to 0$. Now start fiddling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\{a_n\}:=\left\{1\,,\,\frac12\,,\,-\frac13\,,\,-\frac14\,,\,\frac15\,,\,\frac16\,,\,-\frac17\,,\,-\frac18\,,\,\frac19\,,\,\frac1{10}\,,\ldots\right\}$$

Comment: As it is said in this answer $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}}{n}$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Nice example, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$\{a_n\}:=\left\{\frac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3^2},\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{3^3},\frac{1}{2^3},\cdots \right\}$$

Here even $\sum a_n$ converges, $a_n$ is positive,  but $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ has a subsequence that $\rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: Which subsequence is divergent?

Comment: @MariusJonsson The subsequence $3/2, 3^2/2^2, 3^3/2^3, \cdots$ is divergent.

Comment: That is not a subsequence of $\{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

Comment: @MariusJonsson I was wrong. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$ a_n=\frac{2+(-1)^n}{2^n}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2-(-1)^n}{4+2\cdot (-1)^n}=\frac32,\frac16,\frac32,\frac16,\frac32,\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(a_m)=(1,-1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\cdots)$$

then  $$(\frac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}) = (-1,-\frac{1}{2},+1,\frac{-3}{2},-1,\frac{4}{3},+1,\cdots)$$

Essentially, the idea here is that the first sequence is just defined with the denominators decreasing as they are, repeating every term once and changing signs as needed so that the second sequence contains the subsequence $$(-1,+1,-1,+1,\cdots )$$ which clearly doesn't converge. (we don't really care about terms like $-\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{4}{3}$ etc).